# Automated Recording Tools

Tags: .net, automated-tests

Is there any good test recording tools that can record the actions that are performed on a .Net application?

I am doing desktop .Net application, and sometimes users can crash the application after a series of long-winded steps. So in this case, a test recording tool is helpful as it can collect the mouse clicks and mouse actions the users do.

Any idea?

**Edit: Question edited**

Answer (score 0):

Quick Test Pro, but it's not cheap to say the least.

https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24^1352_4000_100__

Comment: What a fantastic URL. Really easy to remember innit?

Comment: HP and IBM web sites are impossible to navigate!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you are looking for.  Your question title and body don't seem to be about the same thing.  Your title seems to imply you want a test automation tool, but your body implies you are after something to log/capture the events of a manual testing session for debugging.  These are 2 different things.  Could you clarify?

If you are looking for test automation tools for creating a test automation suite, see some of these related posts.  There are a bunch of tools out there, including HP QTP, IBM Rational Functional Tester, IBM Rational Robot, Borland SilkTest, Compuware TestPartner, etc...

- [tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows)
- [gui-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92059/gui-testing)
- [automated-testing-of-windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701603/automated-testing-of-windows-forms)
- [List of GUI testing tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools)

Answer (score 0):

As Tom E said, your question is confusing. You need a library that can capture and log user actions, not a test automation tool. The one I know about is [TestRecorder](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testrecorder/); here's an extract from its description:

> TestRecorder is a set of runtime libraries to be distributed with your 32-bit and 64-bit applications. Once incorporated into your application, TestRecorder fully records end-user actions in the binary format. Later, the recorded data can be converted with TestComplete to a keyword test or easily readable script code in VBScript, JScript, DelphiScript, C++Script or C#Script. These scripts tell you exactly what a user was doing during application execution — allowing you to accurately repeat the sequence of user actions via TestComplete or TestExecute.