# Automated user testing with times

Tags: testing, automated-tests, autotest

I am attempting to test user interaction with an off the shelf product.

The current process is to run through a manual script and record how long certain processes take to populate data, it may populate a datagrid, a tree, a list box, etc...
It will also need to be able record how long it takes to generate a pdf report.
We do not require extremely accurate time just to the nearest second or less than a second.

I need to know if there is a simple Automated testing product that will handle the above criteria.

Comment: What operating system does your off the shelf product run on ?  Is it a standalone app or do you access it with a web browser ?  The answers will help to narrow down the list of tool.

Comment: The product runs natively in windows as client, it also has a terminal server functionality similar to hyper-v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to a previous answer of mine with links to other posts on the same topic. But there are quite a few commercial and open source gui automation solutions out there.

[Automated Recording Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883531/automated-recording-tools/893001#893001)

---

Update based on terminal server comment:

Unfortunately if your are dealing with a terminal server app, the terminal part of the client ui is going to be seen by most automation tools as a single bitmap.

However, you may be able to try automation tools like [CitraTest](http://www.tevron.com/citratest.asp) or [Eggplant](http://www.testplant.com/) or [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/), which are image-based, rather than object-based.

Comment: I tried using AutoIT which was awesome for the client side part of the product.

When it came to the products terminal server-ish (very similar to Hyper-V in functionality) side of the product AutoIT could not "see" the application. 

I am not sure of any product will be able to help me in that case as it is a proprietary terminal server app, and may be inherently un-automatable.