# automate user interface test

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests

I'm looking for a way to automate testing on my program's user interface.

Let me explain:
I have this program with a user interface. My programs makes calls to a web service. And that web service modifies data in my database.

For test purpose I need to do a whole lot of user interface manipulations. This is long and annoying...

So I'm looking for a "recorder" that will save my actions (click on this button, insert text on the textbox, choose an option on a drop down menu, click on ok, etc.) and keep them for testing repeatedly.

I've heard about WHITE but I'm interested in proposals...

ANY IDEAS?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

Link to a previous answer of mine with links to other posts on the same topic. But there are quite a few commercial and open source gui automation solutions out there.

[Automated Recording Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883531/automated-recording-tools/893001#893001)